# Uploading documents from Amazon S3 to CloudSearch using .NET SDK

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudsearch

Using Command Line Tool, if we run the command `cs-import-documents` we can directly upload the data from Amazon S3 to CloudSearch Domain.For example,

```
cs-import-documents -d searchdev3 --source s3://mybucket/html
```

I need to use the equivalent of this command to use in .NET SDK.

But all I found for this is `AmazonCloudSearchDomainClient` class which allows us to upload file from local system by providing path; which I think is equivalent to following command-

```
aws cloudsearchdomain --endpoint-url http://doc-movies-y6gelr4lv3jeu4rvoelunxsl2e.us-east-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com upload-documents --content-type application/json --documents movie-data-2013.json
```

i don't need this. I need to use equivalent of the command `cs-import-documents`.

Comment: If you can't find the .net sdk method; the next best thing is drop to shell and run the command. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands) explains how to run a shell command from C#. If you are not building the command based on user input it is perfectly safe.